# Problemas con las líneas de un árbol

Tags: html, css, css3

Intento hace un árbol con estilos y HTML pero me encontré con este problema, como se aprecia en la imagen de abajo, lo que no se quiere son las lineas que están sombreadas de ROJO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código html

```
<!-- TREEVIEW CODE -->
<div class="treeview">
  <ul>
    <li class="lamb-first-li">
      <a>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            Top level
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            15 Failed Tests
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <ul>

        <li>
          <a>
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                Top level
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                15 Failed Tests
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                Top level
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                15 Failed Tests
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">
                    Top level
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    15 Failed Tests
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                      <div class="row">
                        Top level
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        15 Failed Tests
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                      <div class="row">
                        Top level
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        15 Failed Tests
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- TREEVIEW CODE -->
```

Y este son mis estilos en SCSS:

```
div {
  &.panel:first-child {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  &.treeview {
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    ul:first-child:before {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

.treeview {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #369;
  ul {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    color: #369;
    margin-left: 1em;
    position: relative;
    ul {
      margin-left: 5.5em;
    }
    &:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      border-left: 1px solid;
      bottom: 4.1rem; /* 76px */
    }
  }
  li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4rem 5em;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;

    .container-fluid {
      .row {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        .lamb-link {
          display: inline;
        }
      }
      .lamb-name-module {
        color: nb-theme(color-primary);
      }
    }

  }
  ul {
    li.lamb-first-li:before {
      border: none;
    }
    li:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 60px;
      height: 0;
      border-top: 1px solid;
      margin-top: 30px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 1em;
      left: 0;
    }
  }
}

.tree-indicator {
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/** =================*/
.treeview li {
  a {
    &:hover {
      background: nb-theme(layout-bg);
      color: #000;
      + ul {
        li {
          a {
            background: nb-theme(layout-bg);
            color: #000;
          }
          &::after, &::before {
            border-color: #94a0b4;
          }
        }
        &::before, ul::before {
          border-color: #94a0b4;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  /** =================*/

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100px;
    width: 15rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    color: #8b8b8b;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 11px nb-theme(lamb-menu-hover);
    -transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    span {
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -0.7em;
      display: block;
    }
  }
  button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    outline: 0;
    &:active, &:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
      border: none;
      background: transparent;
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      outline: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Que compilado y puesto todo junto se ve así (NdE: he cambiado algunos colores para que se vean sin problemas):

```css
div.panel:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

div.treeview {
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div.treeview ul:first-child:before {
  display: none;
}

.treeview {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #369;
}

.treeview ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #369;
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

.treeview ul ul {
  margin-left: 5.5em;
}

.treeview ul:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  bottom: 4.1rem;
  /* 76px */
}

.treeview li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4rem 5em;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
}

.treeview li .container-fluid .row {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.treeview li .container-fluid .row .lamb-link {
  display: inline;
}

.treeview li .container-fluid .lamb-name-module {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.treeview ul li.lamb-first-li:before {
  border: none;
}

.treeview ul li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0;
}

.tree-indicator {
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/** =================*/

.treeview li {
  /** =================*/
}

.treeview li a:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  color: #000;
}

.treeview li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  color: #000;
}

.treeview li a:hover+ul li::after,
.treeview li a:hover+ul li::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}

.treeview li a:hover+ul::before,
.treeview li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}

.treeview li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
  width: 15rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: #8b8b8b;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.treeview li a span {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -0.7em;
  display: block;
}

.treeview li button {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  outline: 0;
}

.treeview li button:active,
.treeview li button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="treeview">
  <ul>
    <li class="lamb-first-li">
      <a>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            Top level
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            15 Failed Tests
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <ul>

        <li>
          <a>
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                Top level
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                15 Failed Tests
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                Top level
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                15 Failed Tests
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">
                    Top level
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    15 Failed Tests
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                      <div class="row">
                        Top level
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        15 Failed Tests
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                      <div class="row">
                        Top level
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        15 Failed Tests
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: En lugar de poner el SCSS, sería ideal que pusieras el código CSS compilado, de ese modo podrías crear un snippet directamente en la pregunta para que podamos ver el error. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Las líneas las estás haciendo con una misma sentencia con el borde de un `:before` de los diferentes elementos `ul`. Para ajustar el alto simplemente podrías darle un valor de `height` que se ajuste al esquema.

Dandole clases podemos darle un alto según el número de elementos que tenga por debajo, y asignar a esos el alto del `:before`

```css
/*editado*/
.ul-2:before{
  height: 160px;
}

.ul-1:before {
  height: 47px;
}
/*editado*/

div.panel:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

div.treeview {
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div.treeview ul:first-child:before {
  display: none;
}

.treeview {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #369;
}

.treeview ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #369;
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

.treeview ul ul {
  margin-left: 5.5em;
}

.treeview ul:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  bottom: 4.1rem;
  /* 76px */
}

.treeview li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4rem 5em;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
}

.treeview li .container-fluid .row {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.treeview li .container-fluid .row .lamb-link {
  display: inline;
}

.treeview li .container-fluid .lamb-name-module {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.treeview ul li.lamb-first-li:before {
  border: none;
}

.treeview ul li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0;
}

.tree-indicator {
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/** =================*/

.treeview li {
  /** =================*/
}

.treeview li a:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  color: #000;
}

.treeview li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  color: #000;
}

.treeview li a:hover+ul li::after,
.treeview li a:hover+ul li::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}

.treeview li a:hover+ul::before,
.treeview li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}

.treeview li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
  width: 15rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: #8b8b8b;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.treeview li a span {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -0.7em;
  display: block;
}

.treeview li button {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  outline: 0;
}

.treeview li button:active,
.treeview li button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="treeview">
  <ul>
    <li class="lamb-first-li">
      <a>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            Top level
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            15 Failed Tests
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <ul class="ul-2">

        <li>
          <a>
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                Top level
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                15 Failed Tests
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                Top level
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                15 Failed Tests
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <ul class="ul-1">
            <li>
              <a>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">
                    Top level
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    15 Failed Tests
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>
              <ul class="ul-2">
                <li>
                  <a>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                      <div class="row">
                        Top level
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        15 Failed Tests
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                      <div class="row">
                        Top level
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        15 Failed Tests
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías aplicar lo que mencionas al código de la pregunta? Tal y como está redactada la respuesta, casi parece más un comentario que una respuesta.

Comment: Creo que me he explicado mal, el código que he puesto es para añadirlo al código de la pregunta. ¿Debería copiar y pegar todo el código?

Comment: @asantanao Gracias por la respuesta. Pero el árbol finalmente se creará con datos dinámicos, en ese sentido no seria buena idea ponerle Ids. y si, el código esta desordenado. si pudiese ayudarme estaría agradecido.

Comment: Ok, pero el tamaño está ya definido entiendo, ¿o el árbol puede tener diferentes tamaños? Si no es así, se puede editar el elemento accediendo con selectores sin id

Comment: De pronto el tamaño de los elementos serán el mismo tamaño, pero el tamaño de los enlaces va a depender de la cantidad de hijos que tenga cada _padre_

Comment: En ese caso, lo único que se me ocurre es que en el código cuando los creas dinámicamente, des una clase al ul según el numero de elementos que tenga por debajo, y en los estilos aplicas un alto según cada caso. Edito la respuesta y pongo el ejemplo con clases.

Comment: Gracias, pero en este caso tendría que crear clases para cada caso(cantidad de hijos), y no seria conveniente, para mi caso